# meaning of the expression

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

I'm not a native speaker.  When I watched a sports game on the TV, I heard some expression.

But I have no idea what it means.

> IN a NBA game, A player was dribbling a basketball outstanding. At that time, an announcer said "That's not fair!".

I don't know what "that's not fair." means.

Is there anyone who can talk to me what it means?

Answer (score 1):

It's the main meaning of fair. [Something that is fair is **reasonable, right, and just.**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fair)

It's used humorously. It's not fair that he is so talented/gifted/skilful. They are impressed with his performance.

Comment: Can I accept the meaning that he is so talented or it's not reasonable that he is good at it?

Comment: @bak1936 Both. He is "unreasonably" talented, "unfairly" gifted (it's put humorously).